# What does a lightning bolt symbol next to an antenna connector mean?

Tags: transceiver, jargon, antenna-system, yaesu, equipment

On the back of my Yaesu FT-897, next to each of the antenna connectors, there are lightning-bolt-ish symbols. What do these mean, and is there something I ought to be doing because of that?

I have not found any description of a meaning for these symbols. My best guess so far is that they are warnings of possible high voltage (while transmitting), but they are not enclosed in a triangle as in the standard high-voltage warning symbol. I thought they might be archaic symbols for antennas, but there is an antenna symbol placed between the two connectors.

[image: There is a lightning bolt with arrowhead placed to the left of the left antenna connector, and one placed to the right of the right connector. They each point towards the center of the connector, as opposed to straight down.]

Comment: I'd definitely say that they're unusual electrical shock symbols. I've seen quite a number of electrical shock symbols without a triangle. The angle does seem a bit unusual though.

Comment: I think they're reminders to ground your antenna shields to earth grounds, not to your household receptacle ground due to the danger from high voltages of lightning strikes.

Comment: @WarrenP The "household receptacle ground" *is* an Earth ground. If your household receptacles are on a different ground than your antenna shields, you can be sure a lightning strike will fry your rig, no matter how many lighting or surge protectors you have.

Answer (score 2):

The manual for this unit doesn't seem to explain or call out these symbols.

When talking about these jacks the manual warns about the following:

- don't leave them connected to antennas during lightning storms
- do not place antennas near power lines, or in a way that might allow them to contact power lines
- be aware of RF exposure